# Corrupted SSIS package with error 0xC00CE504

Tags: xml, svn, visual-studio-2008, ssis, format

I have a corrupted SSIS package with the error message:
Failed to load XML due to error 0xC00CE504 "A name was started with an invalid character. Line 13. Column 2". This happens when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into XML document. This can be the result of either providing an incorrect file name to the LoadPackage method or the XML file specified having an incorrect format.

Basically I have created this package and stored in a SVN folder. It worked fine until someone else edited the package and I am not able to open the package in BIDS, nor am I able to run the package through DTexec or DTexecUI. Apparantely it works just fine on the end of the person whom edited it. I would like to know what does the error message mean exactly and how to tackle this issue correctly so that the package runs ok on my end.

Here's lines 13-17:

```
<<<<<<< .mine 
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionBuild">10</DTS:Property> <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionGUID">{1363A1C9-45B2-408F-9EEB-5BE1AEA4831C}</DTS:Property> 
======= 
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionBuild">13</DTS:Property> <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionGUID">{6A0D00D0-438F-49F2-89D6-662C2FEE766E}</DTS:Property> 
>>>>>>> .r582
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Find the package on your local file system. Rename it from `MyPackage.dtsx` to `MyPackage.tmp.dtsx` Do an SVN update. If the package `works` fine, then you had a conflict between your local copy and the version in source control (and the rename "trick" just hid your version) See the book for information on resolving conflicts http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.vsn-models

Comment: Show us Line 13 of the file.  I suspect you had a merge conflict and now have conflict markers (lines starting `<<<<<` and `>>>>>`) in the file.

Comment: @JimGarrison thank you for the reply. <<<<<<< .mine <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionBuild">10</DTS:Property> <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionGUID">{1363A1C9-45B2-408F-9EEB-5BE1AEA4831C}</DTS:Property> ======= <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionBuild">13</DTS:Property> <DTS:Property DTS:Name="VersionGUID">{6A0D00D0-438F-49F2-89D6-662C2FEE766E}</DTS:Property> >>>>>>> .r582

Comment: As I suspected, this is a merge conflict.  You will need to read up on how to resolve merge conflicts.  This is too big a topic for an SO answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison thanks I believe so too. I'm looking into it. Thanks :)