# Error loading 'Package.dtsx' : Failed to load XML due to error 0xC00CE504 "A name was started with an invalid character

Tags: ssis

Please help with a resolution to the error below:

Error loading 'Package.dtsx' :
Failed to load XML due to error 0xC00CE504
"A name was started with an invalid
character. Line 74, Column 5".
This occurs when loading a package and
the file cannot be opened or loaded
correctly into the XML document.
This can be the result of specifying
an incorrect file name to the
LoadPackage method or the specified
XML file has an incorrect format.

I tried making changes to the package. It then fails on deployment with the error above.

Update: With a bit of research, I noticed that the server had been updated a bout 2 weeks ago and thus the XML version on Local machine might just be different from the definition of the Solution. Is there a way to update the MSXML of the solution to that of the Machine, especially when the package seems to have been corrupted by the deployment process explained above.

Comment: What change did you make? Can you revert and try to find exactly what change causing the error. Did you have a look at line 74 as the error suggests?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To your question. I actually added two fields to the tasks in some tasks in the a solution then rebuild the solution. The error started during deployment. To your second QA, the unfortunately line 73 downwards is blank. I am guessing there are missing details in the package not populated during the deployment hence the error.

Comment: Did you check the comments on this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682834/corrupted-ssis-package-with-error-0xc00ce504

Comment: If you can provide a few lines around 74 it would be easier to help.  I myself know nothing about ssis but I may see something.